# Nikkud of the word ים

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot

Why in Tanach, does the word יָם always have a Komatz, even when נסמך/connected to the next word, such as יָם המלח and יָם פלשתים and even when attached with a מקף such as יָם-כנרת (Bamidbar 34:11) Aside from יַם-סוף?

Comment: modern hebrew goes with patach, but they note the inconsistency in Tanach https://hebrew-academy.org.il/topic/hahlatot/grammardecisions/netiyyat-hashem/1-1-%d7%94%d7%a7%d7%9e%d7%a5/#target-2670

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Minchat_Shai_on_Torah%2C_Numbers.34.3.2?lang=he